# Find groups of values by average with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following data:

```
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e11d9e9c96b354478d9f1b2"), 
        "type" : ObjectId("5c57150e4433c100152eed27"), 
        "ppc" : 100, 
        "cycleString" : "Jan 20", 
        "created_at" : ISODate("2020-01-05T12:43:21.943+0000"), 
    }
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e11dc08c96b354478d9f1d4"), 
        "type" : ObjectId("5c57150e4433c100152eed27"), 
        "ppc" : 104, 
        "cycleString" : "Jan 20", 
        "created_at" : ISODate("2020-01-05T12:52:24.985+0000"), 
    }
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e11dc40c96b354478d9f1e7"), 
        "type" : ObjectId("5c57150e4433c100152eed27"), 
        "ppc" : 125, 
        "cycleString" : "Jan 20", 
        "created_at" : ISODate("2020-01-05T12:53:20.967+0000"), 
    }
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e11dcdec96b354478d9f206"), 
        "type" : ObjectId("5c57150e4433c100152eed27"), 
        "ppc" : 126.1, 
        "cycleString" : "Jan 20",
        "created_at" : ISODate("2020-01-05T12:55:20.967+0000"), 
   }
```

and a constant RANGE_PERCENT (% of allowed range from average, for this example lets say 2%).

I need to get a list where this data is grouped by average price. **The tricky part is that the average is changing depends on the selected group**.

For example:
For the following prices [100, 104, 125, 126.1] (sorted by created_at) I should get 2 groups:

```
    Group A:  
    [100, 104]    
    99.96 < 102 < 104.04 (avgMin < averagePrice < avgMax)
```

```
    Group B:  
    [125, 126.1]  
    123.039 < 125.55 < 128.061 (avgMin < averagePrice < avgMax)
```

1. I should calculate first the min and max of each possible group
2. Calculate the possible group average
3. Then get the min and max allowed average

   > avgMin = avg - (avg * RANGE_PERCENT / 100)
   >   avgMax = avg + (avg * RANGE_PERCENT / 100)
4. all the prices fit in that range (avgMin < **price** < avgMax) should be in that group.

   - If and object can fit two groups then it should be decided by the group length.

**This is what I have so far:**

At first, I check the validation for the whole group using the same query as below. If the group is valid then I continue to the next group. If its not valid then I create all the possible combinations for the "inner groups" using the following JS code:

```
    function getCombinations(boxes) {
        let result = [];
        let comb = function (prefix, boxes) {
            for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
                const boxObjId = utils.toMongooseObjectId(boxes[i]._id);
                result.push([...prefix, boxObjId]);
                comb([...prefix, boxObjId], boxes.slice(i + 1));
            }
        }
        comb([], boxes);
        return result;
    }
```

After I have all the potential combinations I sort them by the group length and start to query one by one until I find the first valid group.

My not so efficient query:

```
db.getCollection("boxes").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "type" : ObjectId("5c57150e4433c100152eed27"), 
                "cycleString" : ["Jan 19", "Jan 20"]
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "cycleString" : "$cycleString", 
                    "priceTier" : "$priceTier", 
                    "type" : "$type", 
                    "sealed" : "$sealed"
                }, 
                "averagePpc" : {
                    "$avg" : "$ppc"
                }, 
                "minPpc" : {
                    "$min" : "$ppc"
                }, 
                "maxPpc" : {
                    "$max" : "$ppc"
                }, 
                "boxes" : {
                    "$push" : "$$ROOT"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "averagePpc": 1.0,
                "minPpc": 1.0,
                "maxPpc": 1.0,
                "lowestAsk": 1.0,
                "diff" : {
                    "$subtract" : [
                        "$maxPpc", 
                        "$minPpc"
                    ]
                }, 
                "averagePercent" : {
                    "$multiply" : [
                        "$averagePpc", 
                        2.0, 
                        0.01
                    ]
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "averagePpc": 1.0,
                "minPpc": 1.0,
                "maxPpc": 1.0,
                "lowestAsk": 1.0,
                "diff": 1.0,
                "averagePercent": 1.0,
                "allowedHigh" : {
                    "$add" : [
                        "$averagePpc", 
                        "$averagePercent"
                    ]
                }, 
                "allowedLow" : {
                    "$subtract" : [
                        "$averagePpc", 
                        "$averagePercent"
                    ]
                },
                "boxes": 1.0
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "averagePpc": 1.0,
                "minPpc": 1.0,
                "maxPpc": 1.0,
                "lowestAsk": 1.0,
                "diff": 1.0,
                "averagePercent": 1.0,
                "allowedHigh": 1.0,
                "allowedLow": 1.0,
                "validated" : {
                    "$cond" : {
                        "if" : {
                            "$gte" : [
                                "$maxPpc", 
                                "$allowedHigh"
                            ]
                        }, 
                        "then" : false, 
                        "else" : {
                            "$cond" : {
                                "if" : {
                                    "$lt" : [
                                        "$minPpc", 
                                        "$allowedLow"
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                "then" : false, 
                                "else" : true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, 
                "boxes" : 1.0
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

So my question is, can I somehow make this more efficient? Maybe instead of calling it many times to make it to one query that will also include the JS getCombinations() func in it?

Comment: Provide please sample data. The requirements and query condition are contrary, as you are filtering `"cycleString" : "Dec 19"` all documents will have same date. What is the criteria for 2 groups? AVG for 5 prices is 1012.8, so 2% min/max 992.54/1033.5, so all prices fit `avgMin < price < avgMax`.

Comment: How do you determine the group members - how many items make a group. In the example you say there are two groups A and B from the following  [100, 104, 125, 126.1]. What if the prices are more than 4: 5? or 6? or ..., etc. Or is it just two groups  A and B irrespective of number of prices.

Comment: All possible combinations of the boxes should be a potential group, but only those that are validated by avgMin < price < avgMax for each box in the group are the groups I want to get in the end. Also, I will need to remove duplicates (all the boxes appear in more then one group) but this step is for later..

Comment: I managed to get it to work but not so efficient I guess. How can I improve this?